# google.maps.event.trigger not run when map reload

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a project using Google maps api v3, and I am using `google.maps.event.trigger` to call or trigger the listener that is created when the map loads. In this case I set listener at polygon click, so when polygon is clicked, it opens the relevant infowindow and `google.maps.event.trigger` is set on another block of function in the same javascript file.
It is running well when the whole web program is reloaded. But when I reload the map or map is re-initialized with the polygon with same variable object, the syntax `google.maps.event.trigger` does not run. This is my function that is using `google.maps.event.trigger`

```
 function callInfoPoly(nomor){
    alert(polygon[nomor].getPath().getAt(0));
    google.maps.event.trigger(polygon[nomor], "click");
    }
```

the alert runs well, it means the variable contains the polygon object, but `google.maps.event.trigger` doesn't run.

Comment: can you give a link to that page or create a demo?

Comment: ill try to make demo on fiddle, please wait and thank you for ur respons

Comment: this is some of my code : http://jsfiddle.net/69wZu/4/
but im sory i cant make it works, maybe u can help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you take a look into the console after triggering the click you'll see an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vertex' of undefined
```

This undefined object is a [PolyMouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PolyMouseEvent) . This object will be passed to the click-callback when a real click occurs. But when you trigger the click programmatically this object is missing, what forces the error above(and somehow stops the binding of the click-listener after re-initializing the map ).

solution: pass an empty object as argument to the click-callback when you trigger the click programmatically:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(polygon[nomor], "click", {});
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/jVFN2/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/jVFN2/)

Comment: Google... your API's... woof.  Thanks for figuring this out, took me forever!

Comment: this works, except if you have something like a custom infowindow that expects a location to open to on the map, in that case, you need to provide a polymouseevent (which extends mouseevent) which requires the latLng property so instead of {}, you pass {latLng:new LatLng(etc)}